# How to set if condition on keyup() in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<label id="statusLabel">Online</label>
<input type="text" id="txtInput">

<script>

if($('txtInput').keyup()) {
    
    $('#statusLabel').text('typing...');
}

else {
    
    $('#statusLabel').text('online');
}

</script>
```

I want set statusLabel.text to 'typing' when I'm typing on the keyboard.And statusLabel.text to 'online' when I'm not typing on the keyboard.I have tried this code and It's not working.Is it possible to do so?.Really appreciate if your'll can help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var timerID; 

    $('#txt').keyup(function(){

        $('#status').text('Typing...');

        timerID = setTimeout(clearThis, 1300);
    });

    function clearThis(){

        $('#status').text('online');
        
        clearInterval(timerID);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="status">Online</label>

<br>

<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Answer (score 1):

- This can be done using a timer that gets reset every time a user presses a key in the input field.
- The time is used to show the text **online** after waiting for a certain amount of time when user haven't typed anything, 1 sec in this example.
- So after X amount of millisecond the status is set back to online since system waited for X millisecond before shiting label from **typing...** to **online**.

```js
var timer = null;
$('#txtInput').keydown(() => {
  $('#statusLabel').text('Typing...');
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => $('#statusLabel').text('Online'), 1000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="statusLabel">Online</label>
<input type="text" id="txtInput">
```

Comment: Consider always leaving a note about why your code solves the OP's problems.

Comment: This helped me but can you comment this code what is happening.This is the solution I;m searching for.

Comment: @destr0id i have added the explanation, please check the updated answer now.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you when user start typing then it will show 'typing...' by default after certain time it will show 'online'  :

```
$('txtInput').keyup(function(){

 $('#statusLabel').text('typing...');

    function timer(){
           $('#statusLabel').text('online');
      }
   
   //setTimeout(myFunc,5000);
    setTimeout(timer,3000);   

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var typing;
var interval = 500;

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#txtInput').keyup(function() {
  $('#statusLabel').text('typing...');
  clearTimeout(typing);
  if ($('#txtInput').val()) {
    typing = setTimeout(doneTyping, interval);
  }
});

function doneTyping() {
  $('#statusLabel').text('online')
}
```

Here I use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` so the text dont flash between `typing...` and `online`.

Basic, what it does is that when you start typing, it changes the text, and clears the timer. If you press another key within 0,5 seconds then it will clear the timer once more. 
Once you haven't typed anything for 0,5 sec then it will change the text of `statusLabel`

**Demo**

```js
var typing;
var interval = 500;

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#txtInput').keyup(function() {
  $('#statusLabel').text('typing...');
  clearTimeout(typing);
  if ($('#txtInput').val()) {
    typing = setTimeout(doneTyping, interval);
  }
});

function doneTyping() {
  $('#statusLabel').text('online')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="statusLabel">Online</label>
<input type="text" id="txtInput">
```